# Sync switchable wall outlet with another wall outlet remotely

Tags: remote-control, socket

This could be an existing product (please tell me what is called), or the idea of a new product.

Current setup: a wall outlet in the far end of the room is linked to a a switch near the door. Typically you power a lamp return that outlet, so when you turn switch on, the lamp goes on.
However, I have another lamp powered by a SECOND outlet that's not part of the switch circuit because it's far from the FIRST outlet.

What I want: make that second lamp also turn on and off with the switch.

What I don't want: run an extension cord from the FIRST outlet to the SECOND lamp, that way both lamps are on the same circuit.

My new product idea: in the FIRST outlet, put a TRANSMITTER unit, that when on, it broadcasts a signal out saying ON, and when it turns off, it seems a signal OFF.
In the SECOND outlet, put a RECEIVER unit with a built-in socket, it provides power to that socket on and off based on that signal that's broadcast in the room.

Benefit:

- No need to run extension cords everywhere
- Can have many outlets in three room linked to the same TRANSMITTER unit
- Customize what turned on and off in every room, making the switch at the door more programmable than just ONE outlet.

Does this product exist?
If not, can I build it myself?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, yes.
However, but most people would call an electrician (or investigate themselves) to check if the switched outlet has a traveller wire that provides power to the switched outlet and the outlets beyond (to your unswitched outlet).  If that is the case, it may be possible to simply reconfigure the wires at the switched outlet box.

Answer (score 1):

Does it exist? Maybe. Doubt it. Seems pretty niche.

Can you create it? Yes. Simple enough. There are IR, RF, WiFi, Bluetooth, Powerline, etc type of remote outlets that do the majority of what you want already. That is being able to switch a relay on and off remotely. The rest is just programming a if this then that type setup. You could do this with a microcontroller with a radio module (rf433 or Bluetooth etc) and probably a battery or supercap.

You can find many projects online for microcontroller smart outlets.

Answer (score 0):

There's a product called Switcheroo that does precisely this.

Comment: THANK you... that's exactly what I wanted!
It's a little pricey, though.
I wish I can learn how to make one myself.